# Python SymPy get equation from matrix element

Tags: matrix, sympy, equation

How to get equation from element of matrix in sympy? I have a matrix called _RIGHT. I want to take equation from index 0,3 and copy to eq1. Expected eq1 will be same result in red box.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
eq1 = _RIGHT[0,3]
```

instead of `_RIGHT.row(0).col(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix (`eq1`) has just one element. **that element is an equation** inside a one-by-one matrix.

So, simply use `eq1[0]` to point out exactly the equation.

```py
eq1 = _RIGHT.row(0).col(3)

eq1[0]
```